# Facing errors restoring snapshots via MongoDB Ops Manager to a new deployment created using MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am trying to restore a snapshot of my current deployment to a new deployment via MongoDB Ops Manager. Both the current and new deployment are created using MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator.

However I am facing the following errors reported by Ops Manager:

```
Restore from Backup (RestoreRsMemberFromBackupPhase2)
Check process needs restore from backup (CheckRsMemberNeedsRestorePhase2)
**Fails here -->**SeedRestoreAfterApplyOps the replica set member with an oplog and a replset config (SeedRestoreAfterApplyOps)
Mark automated restore phase finished (MarkRestorePhase2Finished)
```

Looking at the container logs, I found the following errors reported by the automation agent:

```
Plan execution failed on step SeedRestoreAfterApplyOps as part of move RestoreRsMemberFromBackupPhase2 : <proj1-replicaset2-1> 
[10:59:49.939] Failed to apply action. Result = <nil> : <proj1-replicaset2-1> 
[10:59:49.938] Error starting mongo process proj1-replicaset2-1 on ephermal port : <proj1-replicaset2-1> 
[10:59:49.938] Error starting mongo with args = map[net:map[bindIp:0.0.0.0 port:38348 ssl:map[mode:disabled]] replication:map[] setParameter:map[disableLogicalSessionCacheRefresh:true ttlMonitorEnabled:false] storage:map[dbPath:/data] systemLog:map[destination:file path:/var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb.log]] : (res=<nil>) : <proj1-replicaset2-1> 
[10:59:49.937] Error starting mongod : <proj1-replicaset2-1> 
[10:59:49.937] failed to store process id : open forkedProcesses: permission denied
```